# Jquery auto submit on click outside the div

Tags: jquery

what is the simplest way to auto-submit form when the user click out side the div?
Just consider the div not the form elements.

```
<div id="formDiv">
<form id="search">
  <input id="target" type="text" value="Field 1" />
  <input type="text" value="Field 2" />
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you explain what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add a `click` handler to `document` that *isn't* activated inside the `<div>`, like this:

```
$(document).click(function() {
  $("#search").submit();
});
$("#formDiv").click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

What this does, is any click on `document`, results in the `<form id="search">` being submitted, but from inside the `<div>` we stop that `click` event from reaching (bubbling up to) `document` via [`event.stopPropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/).

If the `#search` form may be hidden at times and you only want this to kick in when it's shown for example, no problem, just add a [`:visible`](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) to the selector, like this:

```
$("#search:visible").submit();
```

Comment: If i want to add the functionality of auto submit form while clicking out side the div works only when the user makes changes in the form. other wise it should not auto submit the form.What would be the solution?

Comment: @Muhammad - can you clarify a bit?

Comment: I want to keep the current functionality as described in my question. But I want to add one more thing that it should only submit the form when I have made any change in form.

Comment: @Muhammad - You mean only when you change an input field?

Comment: If i don't change (say textbox value in form) and clicks out side the formDiv, it should not auto submit the form.

Comment: @Muhammad - In that case, you could set a boolean to false, say `var changed = false;` then if it's false (so you only do it once) attach the `document` handler inside the `change`, for example:  `$("#search").change(function() { if(changed) return; $(document).click(function() { $("#search").submit(); }); changed = true; });`, this way that click-to-submit handler doesn't get rigged up *until* something changes.

Comment: This is working but, it is submitting even if i click inside the formDiv.

Comment: @Muhammad - you should still be using the other `.stopPropagation()` handler with that solution, are you?

Comment: @Muhammad - is `#formDiv` being added dynamically, not in the page initially?

Comment: Oh.. Sorry. It was my mistake. Finally, it works.. :) Thanks again

Comment: yes it is added dynamically. I am doing inline editing in table and loading a form dynamically in <tr>

Comment: @Muhammad - ah that's the issue...you've also got me wondering, is the ID unique in the page? and which version of jQuery are you using?  If you're on 1.4.4 then `$("#formDiv").live("click", function(e) { e.stopImmediatePropagation(); });` should work.

Comment: Yes the ID is same, and the same div loads when we click on any row.

Comment: @Muhammad - you can't have an ID repeated like that, it needs to be unique...use a class if it's not going to be unique.  Then use the code from my last comment, just `.formDiv` instead of `#formDiv`.

Comment: @Nic. The solution you told works only first time when i loads the form for editing in any row dynamically and save. After saving if i load the form in any row and don't change form input field data and click out side, it still auto submits the form. Here is your solution var changed = false; $("#search").change(function() { if(changed) return; $(document).click(function() { $("#search").submit(); }); changed = true; });

Answer (score 1):

```
$(#'formDiv').click(function(){
 return false;
});

$(document).click(function() {
  $("#search").submit();
});
```

Comment: This would prevent normal submits, etc from *inside* the `<form>` from working...only use `return false` if you *need* to kill the event, otherwise do what you intend, `.stopPropagation()` in this case, `.preventDefault()` in others.

Answer (score 0):

Write an onclick method in the parent element probably body element in your case and submit the form details.